# Selecting Distinct rows When there is a Logical OR with two columns

Tags: mysql, distinct, logical-or

As the title suggests I have a MySQL query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `friendly_url` FROM `post` WHERE `description` LIKE ? OR `heading` LIKE ? ORDER BY `friendly_url`
```

I have given the string '%' wild card in the parameters so that this works as a Search function. How ever, Say a user is searching for a common word like 'is' and it appears in both heading and description in the same post. Then this query returns the same post twice. I don't want that to happen, hence the 'DISTINCT'.

Why does this happen? Any way I can work around to make it work the way i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is not returning the same row twice. The predicates in the `WHERE` clause are evaulated against each row, and either the row is returned, or it's not. No combination of `OR` conditions is going to cause MySQL to return the "same row" multiple times.

If you are getting duplicate values of `friendly_url`, then you have multiple rows in the `post` table that have the same value for `friendly_url`. (i.e. `friendly_url` column is *not* unique in the `post` table.)

---

You don't have to use the `DISTINCT` keyword to remove duplicates from the resultset. You could remove the `DISTINCT` keyword, and add `GROUP BY friendly_url` before the `ORDER BY` clause.

---

To identify the "duplicated" values of `friendly_url`, and how many rows have that same value:

```
  SELECT p.friendly_url
       , COUNT(1)
    FROM post p
   GROUP BY p.friendly_url
  HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Comment: In what situations do we use DISTINCT then?

Comment: The `DISTINCT` keyword is very convenient when we've got long list of expressions in the `SELECT` list, and we don't want to repeat all of them in a `GROUP BY` clause, and we don't otherwise have a need for a `GROUP BY` (like aggregate expressions MAX, SUM, etc. in the SELECT list.)  There's nothing wrong with using DISTINCT. I was just offering an alternative, if you want to remove duplicates but don't want to use the DISTINCT keyword.